# Snake game in rust

Tags: game, rust, sdl

I made a small rust snake game in order to teach myself rust. I would like to know what I am doing well and poorly, and how to improve my rust code

## Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "snake-rs"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Hurricane996 <levijwillrich@gmail.com>"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
sdl2 = "0.34"
rand = "0.8"

[profile.release]
lto = true
```

## src/main.rs

```
extern crate sdl2;
extern crate rand;

mod constants;
mod fruit;
mod snake;
mod vector2;

use constants::BOARD_WIDTH;
use constants::BOARD_HEIGHT;
use constants::CELL_SIZE;

use fruit::Fruit;

use snake::Snake;

use vector2::Vector2;

use sdl2::event::Event;
use sdl2::keyboard::Keycode;
use sdl2::pixels::Color;

use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let sdl_context = sdl2::init().unwrap();
    let video_subsystem = sdl_context.video().unwrap();
    let window = video_subsystem.window("Rust Snake", BOARD_WIDTH*CELL_SIZE, BOARD_HEIGHT*CELL_SIZE)
        .position_centered()
        .build()
        .unwrap();
    let mut canvas = window.into_canvas().build().unwrap();
    let mut event_pump = sdl_context.event_pump().unwrap();
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let mut snake = Snake::new();
    let mut fruit = Fruit::new();
    let mut frame_counter = 0;
    let mut input_stack = VecDeque::<Vector2>::with_capacity(32);

    fruit.mv(&mut rng);

    'running: loop {
        for event in event_pump.poll_iter() {
            match event {
                Event::Quit {..} => {
                    break 'running;
                },
                Event::KeyDown {keycode,..} => {
                    match keycode.expect("") {
                        Keycode::Up | Keycode:: W => {
                            input_stack.push_front(-Vector2::J);
                        }
                        Keycode::Down | Keycode:: S => {
                            input_stack.push_front(Vector2::J);
                        }
                        Keycode::Left | Keycode:: A => {
                            input_stack.push_front(-Vector2::I);
                        }
                        Keycode::Right | Keycode:: D => {
                            input_stack.push_front(Vector2::I);
                        }
                        _ => {}
                    }
                }
            _ => {}
            }
        }
    
        frame_counter+=1;
        if frame_counter > Snake::SPEED {
            frame_counter = 0;
            snake.mv(&mut input_stack, &fruit);
        
            if !snake.safe() {break 'running; }
          
            if snake.is_eating_fruit(&fruit) {
                fruit.mv(&mut rng);
            }
        }
    
        canvas.set_draw_color(Color::BLACK);
        canvas.clear();
    
        snake.draw(&mut canvas);
        fruit.draw(&mut canvas);
    
        canvas.present();
        std::thread::sleep(Duration::new(0, 1_000_000_000u32 / 60));
    }
}
```

## src/fruit.rs

```
use crate::constants::BOARD_WIDTH;
use crate::constants::BOARD_HEIGHT;
use crate::constants::CELL_SIZE;

use crate::vector2::Vector2;

use rand::Rng;

use sdl2::pixels::Color;
use sdl2::rect::Rect;
use sdl2::render::Canvas;
use sdl2::render::RenderTarget;

pub struct Fruit(pub Vector2);

impl Fruit {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Fruit ( Vector2 {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        })
    }

    pub fn mv<R: Rng>(&mut self, rng: &mut R ) {
        self.0.x = rng.gen_range(0..BOARD_WIDTH) as i32;
        self.0.y = rng.gen_range(0..BOARD_HEIGHT) as i32;
    }

    pub fn draw<T: RenderTarget>(&mut self, canvas: &mut Canvas<T>) {
        canvas.set_draw_color(Color::RED);
        canvas.fill_rect(Rect::new(self.0.x * CELL_SIZE as i32, self.0.y * CELL_SIZE as i32, CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE)).unwrap();
    }
}
```

## src/snake.rs

```
use crate::constants::BOARD_HEIGHT;
use crate::constants::BOARD_WIDTH;
use crate::constants::CELL_SIZE;
use crate::fruit::Fruit;
use crate::vector2::Vector2;

use sdl2::pixels::Color;
use sdl2::rect::Rect;
use sdl2::render::Canvas;
use sdl2::render::RenderTarget;

use std::collections::VecDeque;

pub struct Snake {
    direction: Vector2,

    head: Vector2,
    body: VecDeque::<Vector2>
}

impl Snake {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let mut s = Snake {
            head: Vector2::new((BOARD_WIDTH/2) as i32, (BOARD_HEIGHT/2) as i32),
            direction: Vector2::I,
            body: VecDeque::<Vector2>::with_capacity((BOARD_WIDTH*BOARD_HEIGHT) as usize),
        };
  
        for i in 1..(Self::INITIAL_SIZE) {
            let i = i as i32;
            s.body.push_back(Vector2::new(s.head.x - i, s.head.y))
        }

        return s;
    }

    pub fn mv(&mut self, input_stack: &mut VecDeque::<Vector2>, fruit: &Fruit) {
        //this pushes the old head, so the body does not contain the head.
        self.body.push_front(self.head);

        'process_input: loop {
            let maybe_input = input_stack.pop_back();
        
            match maybe_input {
                Some(input) => {
                    if input != self.direction && input != -self.direction {
                        self.direction = input;
                        break 'process_input;
                    }
                }
                None => { break 'process_input; }
           }
        
        }
        
        self.head = self.head + self.direction;

        if self.head != fruit.0 {
            self.body.pop_back();
        }
    }

    pub fn is_eating_fruit(&self, fruit: &Fruit) -> bool {
        self.head == fruit.0 || self.body.iter().any(|&i|i==fruit.0)
    }
  
    pub fn safe(&self) -> bool {
        !(
            self.body.iter().any(|&i|i==self.head) ||
            self.head.x < 0||
            self.head.y < 0 ||
            self.head.x >= BOARD_WIDTH as i32 ||
            self.head.y >= BOARD_HEIGHT as i32
        )
    }

    pub fn draw<T: RenderTarget>(&self, canvas: &mut Canvas<T>) {
        canvas.set_draw_color(Color::GREEN);

        canvas.fill_rect(Rect::new(self.head.x * CELL_SIZE as i32, self.head.y * CELL_SIZE as i32, CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE)).unwrap();

        for segment in &self.body {
            canvas.fill_rect(Rect::new(segment.x * CELL_SIZE as i32, segment.y * CELL_SIZE as i32, CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE )).unwrap();
        }
    }

    pub const SPEED: u32 = 15;

    const INITIAL_SIZE: u32 = 3;
}
```

## src/Vector2.rs

```
use std::ops;

#[derive(Copy,Clone,PartialEq)]
pub struct Vector2 {
    pub x: i32,
    pub y: i32
}

impl Vector2 {
    pub fn new(x: i32, y: i32) -> Vector2 {
        Vector2 {
            x: x,
            y: y
        }
    }

    pub const I : Vector2 = Vector2 {x: 1,y: 0};
    pub const J : Vector2 = Vector2 {x: 0,y: 1};
}

impl ops::Add<Vector2> for Vector2 {
    type Output = Self;
    fn add(self, rhs: Self) -> Self::Output {
        Vector2 {
            x: self.x + rhs.x,
            y: self.y + rhs.y
        }
    }
}

impl ops::Neg for Vector2 {
    type Output = Self;

    fn neg(self) -> Self::Output {
        Vector2 {
            x: -self.x,
            y: -self.y
        }
    }
}
```

## src/constants.rs

```
pub const BOARD_HEIGHT: u32 = 16;
pub const BOARD_WIDTH: u32 = 16;

pub const CELL_SIZE: u32 = 32;
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, there are some quick things I'd change. `extern crate [crate name];` is not needed in the 2018 edition of rust, and as such can be removed. Running `clippy` also shows some easy changes - firstly, in the `Vector2::new` function, you can change `Vector2 { x: x, y: y }` to `Vector2 { x, y }`. You can also replace the `return s;` with just `s` in `Snake::new`, as if a semicolon is omitted on the last line of a block, the value is returned.

There are also some style decisions I would personally change. Firstly, running `cargo fmt` can clean up a lot of minor issues (such as no spaces between items in the derive macros). Another is your using statements - you can replace

```rust
use constants::BOARD_HEIGHT;
use constants::BOARD_WIDTH;
use constants::CELL_SIZE;
```

with

```rust
use constants::{BOARD_HEIGHT, BOARD_WIDTH, CELL_SIZE};
```

which personally I prefer, but it is up to you. Similar things can be done with the other blocks, such as

```rust
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::time::Duration;
```

to

```rust
use std::{collections::VecDeque, time::Duration};
```

Now for code changes:

- The `'running` label in `main` and the `'process_input` in `Snake::mv` should be removed as there are no nested loops, so a normal `break` works fine. In general, you only want to use labels for situations like wanting to break out of an outer loop while in an inner loop.
- The `.unwrap()` calls can be replaced with `.expect([error message])` calls if you still want to panic on failures, but using expect will give more information. This will make it easier to spot what is actually going wrong.
- Functions and structs should have doc comments explaining what they're doing. For example, `Vector2::I` could be commented as follows to better explain it. This is not strictly necessary, but most editors will show the text when function calls/constants/structs are hovered over, so it can help a lot with understanding what programs are doing.

```rust
/// The unit vector representing (1, 0).
pub const I: Vector2 = Vector2 { x: 1, y: 0 };
```

- Type annotations on `input_stack` in `main` and `body` in `Snake::new` for `VecDeque::<Vector2>` can be removed - so

```rust
let mut input_stack = VecDeque::<Vector2>::with_capacity(32);
```

would become

```rust
let mut input_stack = VecDeque::with_capacity(32);
```

And for what you've done well:

- Using traits for operations such as `Add` is a very good habit.
- Good use of iterators in functions like `Snake::safe`. Iterators are almost always more idiomatic than alternatives, so it is a good idea to get comfortable to using them (as well as methods like `map` and `fold`).
- Initializing vectors with a given capacity is very handy for reducing the number of re-allocations, and this is a perfect use case for them - since you know the upper bound of how many items will ever be in the vector.
- Using constants throughout your code (such as `Snake::SPEED`), compared to the alternative of littering magic numbers throughout your code.